# Lightbox effects not working onnext gen gallery

Tags: wordpress, lightbox, nextgen-gallery

I have been trying to debug this problem for a few days but have come to no solution yet. I have tried all the various settings and they are all correct. The scripts and css seem to point to the correct files.

I cant get any lightbox effects to work on my next gen galleries with the theme 'Zendion'. I have previewed a few other themes and lightbox works with all of them correctly. I have disabled all other plugins and still have had no joy. An example is here

http://www.fionanoconnell.com/?p=1311

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zendion is a fairly old theme that I don't believe has been updated since 2010. Next Gen is generally pretty compatible with light boxes, but sometimes things fall through the cracks (eg http://wordpress.org/support/topic/gallery-thumbs-link-to-media-file). You could try deregistering whatever light box Zendion is calling and installing a new one in its place... but honestly it may be best to simply use a different theme. A fair amount has changed in WordPress since 2010, and an older theme like that, especially one that puts as much functionality into the theme as that one did, is fairly likely to run into speed bumps and incompatibilities. I think you'd best off using a new theme.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if a different light box plugin will work. Its strange though, to me everything looks as if its being called correctly. I also hard coded the lightbox scripts in and still nothing

Comment: I've tried another plugin - NextGEN Gallery ColorBoxer. Still no joy. Everything seems to be in position to for it to work. Does anyone know any reason the script wouldnt fire?